# Custom Shipping Method - creates error in cart update

Tags: shipping, custom-options

I followed the suggestions in the following [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5620/magento-custom-shipping-rate), The answer was perfect except for the fact I now have this error when I update my shopping cart no of items. If I press back the cart updates but I dont want this error.

Error :

> There has been an error processing your request    Error log no :
>   xxxxxxxxx (some numbers)

I followed the inchoo method of creating my own shipping method.

The error log indicates a problem on line 5 of the php file :
   `extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract`

Hmm... not sure ?

Comment: Check the `var/report` folder of your magento instance, for a file with the same name as the error log number. Inside it you should find the error message. maybe that helps. If it doesn't add the error message to your question

Comment: a:5:{i:0;s:149:"Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /home/dktechno/public_html/magento/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Dktech.php, line 74";i:1;s:1874:"#0 /home/dktechno/public_html/magento/magento/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(148): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)

Comment: So I think its something that I might have done wrong in the dktech.php file - unfortunately I cant place the whole error log - this doesnt allow for that many characters - but I'm sure thats the problem line ?

Comment: Make sure you don't have any space chars at the beginning of the file, before `<?php` or at the end after `?>`. in fact remove the closing php tag if you have one.

Comment: I checked that - not the prob. Should I send you the php file ? What I'm worried about is that I've done this differently to the way suggested in the previous solution - not sure as the entire file wasnt posted. However I tried it a different way - tehre are no cart errors , but also no shipping output, so thats wrong too.

Comment: you can edit the question and add your file

Comment: Sorry this was my fault - I never read your comment properly - didnt see the bit about removing the closing php tag. this worked - why ?

Comment: This is why: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3219401/2047249

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :) I'm just glad its all working . I read that comment - still not sure why I had a problem, def no blank space, buts its great to learn something new.