# Adding multiple "per-item" shipping options

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, shipping

I need two have two "per-item" shipping options, with different base prices and per-item rates. Standard shipping, not usps/ups/fedex. It doesn't seem like there's a good way to do this. I've read about setting up multiple flat rates, but I don't believe that applies to this situation. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Create a custom shipping method. take a look here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/5624/146. Is not exactly what you need but it should give you an idea. This might help also: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/7565/146

Answer (score 1):

Its a little unclear exactly what you want to do here, but as Marius says you need to create a carrier based extension for this one.

You can then get access inside the $request object to the items ($request->getAllItems()) and also get access to any attributes you set up on the products (see http://www.atwix.com/magento/custom-product-attribute-quote-order-item/).

Inchoo has a good tutorial on creating shipping carriers: http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-shipping-method-in-magento/

Answer (score -3):

You can create unlimited number of shipping options based on different conditions with the help of an advanced extension like [Shipping Table Rates](http://amasty.com/shipping-table-rates.html).

Create any number of shipping methods: multiple flat rates, multiple table rates, etc. Flat and percent rates. Combinations of address, weight, price and quantity to calculate shipping. Import rates and edit them manually.

[image]

Comment: I'm not doubting that your extensions solve many issues in listed in here. But if all you do is promote them specially on questions that have an accepted answer (not the case for this one), I think you're here for the wrong reasons.